# Is there any standard solution for buffering output operations in C++?

Tags: c++, buffering

I wrote this simple class that provides buffering for general output operation:

```
template <typename T>
class WriteBuffer {
        typedef void (&flush_t)(const T* values, const size_t size);

    public:
        WriteBuffer(size_t size, flush_t flush) : flush_(flush) {
            v_.reserve(size);
        }

       ~WriteBuffer() { flush(); }

        void flush() {
            if (v_.size() > 0) {
                flush_(&v_[0], v_.size());
                v_.clear();
            }
        }

        void write(const T value) {
            if (v_.size() == v_.capacity())
                flush();
            v_.push_back(value);
        }

    private:
        vector<T> v_;
        flush_t flush_;
};
```

(Error checking is omitted for simplicity.) The following example program:

```
void writeInt(const int* values, const size_t size) {
    cout << "Writing buffer of size " << size << ": " << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << values[i] << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WriteBuffer<int> buffer(5, writeInt);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 18; ++i)
        buffer.write(i);

    return 0;
}
```

then generates the following output:

```
Writing buffer of size 5: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
Writing buffer of size 5: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
Writing buffer of size 5: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
Writing buffer of size 3: 15, 16, 17,
```

Is there any standard/better solution of this problem, e.g. some STL container / BOOST class with similar capabilities? Thanks!

Additional question: Would you prefer using function object instead of function reference `flush_t`?

### EDIT

I would like to use such buffering for any type `T` and any `flush` operation provided by the client (not only characters and output streams). For example:

```
template <typename T>
void write(const T* values, const size_t size) {
    ...
    H5Dwrite(..., values);
    ...
}

WriteBuffer<unsigned long> buffer(8192, write<unsigned long>);
```

to write data into HDF5 dataset. (Not solving here HDF5 data types.)

Comment: Are you considering the option of in memory databases ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: Sorry, I know almost nothing about IMDBs. I just need to write a large amount of (sequentially generated) data into a HDF5 file and don't want to call `H5Dwrite()` every such time (measured poor performance against buffered writing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard solution is to subclass [`std::streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/), which was exactly designed for your task. There is some [`boost` magic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) to ease implementation.

Comment: Thanks for tips. As for `std::streambuf`, citing: _base buffer class for streams; streambuf objects are in charge of providing reading and writing functionality to/from certain types of character sequences, such as external files or strings._ But I'm looking for general solution that works with any type (not just characters) and any output (not just streams) provided by the client. Can `std::streambuf` do this?

Comment: @Daniel: `std::streambuf` does not know about the actual objects stored, it is just an interface for bare memory buffering (it uses `char`). It is the underlying buffering mechanism to standard iostreams which are, as you may know, templated on the actual character type. One could easily imagine to use `streambuf` objects for storing any object type. You may want to serialize your objects before putting them into the `streambuf` though, since it won't handle object management at all. It depends on what you intend to use the buffer class for.

Comment: @Daniel: since you're using HDF5, it will suit your needs, since serializing numerical data is (almost) trivial.

Answer (score 1):

cout is by default buffered output.  Your use of endl forces the buffer to flush it's output, but you can use "\n" intead.  If you're program requires the use of either the flag unitbuf, or the manipulators flush or endl and you want to avoid flushing the buffer, you can supposedly use a special stream buffer that does not use sync() to flush the stream buffer, but I've never had a need to, so I'm unclear on the implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't want to use this for standard output or streams, this was just an example. Please, see my comment below the question about HDF5.